Is the choice of a branch of the logarithm arbitrary when dealing with complex powers?
A large section of the book "Complex Analysis with Applications" by Asmar and Grafakos is dedicated to the evaluation of real improper integrals using complex analysis, namely contour integrals.
One exercise asks to establish the identity: $$\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{x^p}{x(1-x)}dx =\pi \cot(p\pi),$$ for $0<p<1.$
We consider the following complex integral $$\int_{\gamma} \frac{z^p}{z(1-z)}dz$$ where $\gamma$ is the contour suggested by the authors (I hope everything is fine with the copyrights):
The idea is to let $R \to +\infty$ and $r \to 0^+$, where $r$ denotes the radius of the small circumferences around the singularities.
Let me point out that the dashed line is a branch cut of the logarithm, that is the ray through the origin along which a branch of the logarithm is discontinuous. Thus, I guess the authors here are choosing $$x^p = \exp(p \log_0(x)),$$ where $\log_0(z) := \ln|z| + i \arg_0 z$ and $0 < \arg_0(z) \le 2 \pi$ (not a multivalued function); in general the complex power is a multivalued function, since it is defined as $$z^a := \exp(a \log z),$$ where $\log z = \ln|z| + i \arg z$ and $\arg z = \{\text{Arg}z + 2k \pi: k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ with $-\pi < \text{Arg} z \le \pi.$
Let us focus on the two semicircles around $1$. Let $\gamma_1$ be the circle around $0$ and follow the direction of the arrow, so that the semicircle around $1$ which is above the $x-$axis will be denoted by $\gamma_3$ and the semicircle around $1$ which is below the $x-$axis will be denoted by $\gamma_7.$
Using the following lemma, which is called the "Shrinking Path Lemma" in the book, we can evaluate the integrals over $\gamma_3$ and $\gamma_7$.

Suppose that $f$ is a continuous complex-valued function on a closed disk $\overline {B_{r_0}(z_0)}$ with center at $z_0$ and radius $r_0$. For $0<r\le r_0$, let $\sigma_r$ denote the positively oriented circular arc at angle $\alpha$, consisting of all $z=z_0 + r e^{i\theta}$, where $\theta_0 \le \theta \le \theta_0 + \alpha$, $\theta_0$ and $\alpha$ are fixed, and $\alpha \neq 0.$ Then $$\lim_{r \to 0^+} \frac{1}{i\alpha} \int_{\sigma_r} \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0} dz = f(z_0)$$


In the following I will refer to $\gamma_3$; a similar argument holds for $\gamma_7$. We would like to apply this lemma to $f(z):=\frac{z^p}{z}$. Observe that $\log_0(z) = \ln|z| + i \arg_0 z$, $0 < \arg_0(z) \le 2 \pi$ is discontinuous on the positive real axis. Therefore we use the following trick: in the first quadrant $\arg_0(z) = \text{Arg z}$, so $\log_0(z) = \text{Log z}$, which is continuous. Thus $$ \int_{\gamma_3} \frac{z^p}{z(1-z)} dz = -\int_{\gamma_3} \frac{z^p}{z(z-1)} dz = -\int_{\gamma_3} \frac{\exp(p \cdot \text{Log z})}{z(z-1)} dz \xrightarrow{r \to 0^+} i \pi \frac{\exp(p \cdot \text{Log 1})}{1} = i \pi$$
(note the change of sign due to the negative orientation of $\gamma_3$).
As you can see, a key step in the use of this lemma for my integral is to manipulate the choice of the original branch of the logarithm.  But shouldn't the complex power be treated as a multifunction? Why is the choice of a branch, namely $\log_0$, non-restrictive?
I know that the substitution $x = e^t$ in the first integral helps overcome most of this trouble, but I wonder why choosing a branch works and whether this is actually the best branch cut to choose: I thought it would be natural to use $\text{Log z}$ (which is discontinuous on the negative real axis), since I have to compute the integral on the positive real axis and thus I could "ignore" that part.
NOTE: I had asked quite a different question before, aimed at finding the mistake in one of my approaches (I had different results for the same integral). Since @Adayah spotted it, I took the opportunity to modify my question and focus it on this doubt I wish to clear up.

If $\gamma_3$ has $|z-1|=r$, then how do you change $z$ to $r$ in the "integral over $\gamma_3$ is null" calculations? Anyway, in the limit as $r \to 0^+$ one of the integrals should be $\pi i$ and the other should be $1^p \pi i$ if I'm not mistaken, so none is null.

Yeah, the second approach correctly proves that the integral over $\gamma_3$ equals $\pi i$ in the limit. In the first approach I think you confused $\gamma_3$ with a semicircle around $0$ or something similar.

@Adayah that's exactly what happened, excellent eyesight though. At this point I wonder if I should delete my question or it is possible to modify it to focus on how to deal with complex powers

I think it's fine to modify the question if you still have some.

I hope I am understanding correctly. And if I am, then it shouldn't matter.
$\gamma$ doesn't enclose or touch poles (0 and 1) or branch points (0 again). Then $$\oint\limits_{\gamma}\frac{z^p}{z(1-z)}dz=0$$
When we use $z^p=\exp(p\operatorname{Ln}(z))$, we find, I assume, $$\oint\limits_{\gamma}\frac{\exp(p\operatorname{Ln}(z))}{z(1-z)}dz=0\implies\pi i+\text{stuff}=0\implies\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^p}{x(1-x)}dx=p\cot(\pi p)$$
Now let's use a different branch. $$z^p=\exp(p\ln_{k}(z))=\exp(p\operatorname{Ln}(z)+p2\pi ki)=\exp(p\operatorname{Ln}(z))\exp(p2\pi ki)$$
We instead find
$$\oint\limits_{\gamma}\frac{\exp(p\operatorname{Ln}(z))\exp(p2\pi ki)}{z(1-z)}dz=0$$
which is the same selection of integrals, with a common scalar multiple.
$$\oint\limits_{\gamma}\frac{\exp(p\operatorname{Ln}(z))\exp(p2\pi ki)}{z(1-z)}dz=0\implies\exp(p2\pi ki)\pi i+\exp(p2\pi ki)\text{stuff}=0\implies\pi i+\text{stuff}=0\implies\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^p}{x(1-x)}dx=p\cot(\pi p)$$

This looks fine: the fact that there is a scalar multiple which disappears looks like the right thing. Thanks!
